# Unexplained Maven Release Plugin behaviour

Tags: git, maven, nexus, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to use maven-release-plugin in our project release process. At first I tried to perform deploy, but instead of **release** repository maven uploads artifacts to **snapshot** repo and doesn't push to SCM:

`Uploading: http://192.168.59.103:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/...../1.15.0-SNAPSHOT/azkabanflow-distribution-1.15.0-20141022.145508-1-sources.jar`

Then, I added next lines:

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.5.1</version>
       <dependencies>
         <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
             <version>1.8.1</version>
         </dependency>
       </dependencies>
 </plugin>
```

Now, it uploads fine to proper repository and pushes to SCM. What's the reason and is there any way to avoid it?

I run this script:

```
git checkout -b release-${RELEASE_VERSION}
mvn -s ~/.m2/settings.xml.bac release:prepare -DautoVersionSubmodules=true -DdevelopmentVersion=${RELEASE_VERSION}.1-SNAPSHOT -DpushChanges=true -DreleaseVersion=${RELEASE_VERSION}.0 -Dtag=v${RELEASE_VERSION}.0
mvn -s ~/.m2/settings.xml.bac release:perform
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-812, however, that should already be fixed in 2.5. Be aware that the Maven Release Plugin 2.5.x releases are first of all Git related releases, which started by the requirement to support Git 1.8+ if I recall correctly. If you only changed maven-scm-provider-gitexe to an earlier version, then have a look at https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SCM/component/12667#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Acomponent-changelog-panel and maybe you can help us identify the problem and fix it for the community.

Comment: Thanks for notifying about 1.8+ requirement. I think, I need to downgrade release-plugin version because our CICD environment still uses 1.7.1, while on my Mac it.s 2.0.4

Comment: I downgraded to plugin version 2.4.2 and SCM is 1.9.2, where bug is fixed. Still, if I declare no such plugin, I get the previous result

Comment: I'm not sure if SCM 1.9.2 will work. It's using the --porcelain option which is quite new. I would expect that in your case m-release-p 2.4.2 without adjustments should work.

Comment: 2.4.2 for MRP `mvn -s ~/.m2/settings.xml.bac org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.4.2:prepare -DautoVersionSubmodules=true -DdevelopmentVersion=${RELEASE_VERSION}.1-SNAPSHOT -DpushChanges=true -DreleaseVersion=${RELEASE_VERSION}.0 -Dtag=v${RELEASE_VERSION}.0` with no SCM plugin version explicitly setting, unfortunately gives the same result. `maven-scm-providers-git` is downloading 1.7, 1.8.1 and 1.9, seems to use 1.9. Is there any way to set version of scm-providers in the command line?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that multiple versions are downloaded. If you run it with an additional -X you'll change the logging lever to debug. Yes, it will be huge, but it will also show you which dependencies are actually use by Maven at runtime. Would be nice if you could share this output somehow (pastebin.com ?).

Comment: Sure, I'll do it asap

Comment: Here we go: prepare: https://gist.github.com/ka2m/8e8561e3c0b2be52e104 and perform: https://gist.github.com/ka2m/a604f06b7b68cc23054f

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ka2m/8e8561e3c0b2be52e104#file-gistfile1-txt-L175 shows that SCM-1.7 is used. Anyhow it all looks like you're hitting indeed MRELEASE-812, which was fixed in 2.5. Brings me back to your original question: What's the reason? You must have been using an older version of the maven-release-plugin. Be aware that if you don't define it in your pom, the predefined version of the Maven distribution is used (and not the latest, just to keep stable builds).  Is there any way to avoid it? Defining it in in the pom.xmlis always the best solution.

Comment: Is there any way to use 2.5 with SCM-1.7? I can't use newer SCM as on our Jenkins machine git 1.7 is installed and has to be there

Comment: I don't remember a change in the SCM-api, so that should be possible, just like you already did. There are 2 dependencies you should set: `org.apache.maven.scm:maven-scm-api:jar` and `org.apache.maven.scm:maven-scm-providers-standard:pom`. Btw, scm-1.7 doesn't mean git-1.7. It's a coincidence they're the same.

Comment: Simple answer: No, only by `pom.xml`.

Comment: Ok, format this as an answer and I will accept it. Many thanks to spending time on this issue. Now I can fully report and complete the task.